# 508 Standards SOA test / link for adobe and microsoft

Tags: html, pdf, ms-word, section508, shockwave

I'm using SOA test reports to find 508 compliance errors. If you do not know what 508 is then refer to this link: [508 Standards Website](http://www.section508.gov/)

**Issue 1:**

```
Section 508 - 1194.22: Warning: Link may be required for document plug-in.
```

This error happens because there is no link to adobe or microsoft in the html document to view word and pdf documents. I'm getting this error for these lines:

```
<a href="hello.pdf">Hello</a>
<a href="world.doc">World</a>
```

I added these 2 lines to the html document fix these errors but the errors still persist:

```
<a href="http://get.adobe.com/reader/">Adobe PDF Download</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4">Word Viewer Download</a>
```

**Issue 2:**

```
Section 508 - 1194.22: Warning: Link may be required for plug-in.
```

This error is the same as the one in issue 1 except I don't need a link to view pdf or word documents; I need a link to view shockwave. I'm getting the error in this code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
```

Again I added this line and the error still persists:

```
<a href="http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/">ShockWave Download</a>
```

Comment: I added the title attribute to the <a> and <object> tags and 508 errors are still being thrown. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contact Parasoft Support. This message is just a warning and apparently gets thrown whether the link is provided or not.